# whitespace in regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have a question, can I say `\t` is equivalent to `\s+` in regular expression.?
I have some lines of code :

```
>>> b = '\tNadya Carson'
>>> c = re.compile(r'\s\s*')
>>> c
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x02729800>
>>> c.sub('',b)
'NadyaCarson'
>>> c = re.compile(r'\s\s+')
>>> c
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x027292F0>
```

There is pattern object till here but when I want to substitute with no space, it still shows \t instead of substituting it:

```
>>> c.sub('',b)
'\tNadya Carson'
```

Why is the attribute sub not working in this case.? Thank you.!

Comment: `\t` is the escape sequence for tab only. `\s` is the special escape for space, tab, newline etc.

Comment: When you use `\s\s+` you are looking for a space followed by 1 or more spaces. It will not match `\tNadya`, in fact it won't match any letter at all.

Comment: @Havenard: Say rather that `\s\s+` matches a *whitespace character* followed by one or more *whitespace characters*.  I know that's what you meant, but it's important to be precise in your phrasing when you're talking to regex beginners.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`\t` is not equivalent to `\s+`, but `\s+` should match a tab (`\t`).

The problem in your example is that the second pattern `\s\s+` is looking for *two* or more whitespace characters, and `\t` is only one whitespace character.

Here are some examples that should help you understand:

```
>>> result = re.match(r'\s\s+', '\t')
>>> print result
None
>>> result = re.match(r'\s\s+', '\t\t')
>>> print result
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10ff228b8>
```

`\s\s+` would also match `' \t'`, `'\n\t'`, `' \n  \t \t\n'`.

Also, `\s\s*` is equivalent to `\s+`. Both will match one or more whitespace characters.

Comment: `\s` alone should also match to `\t`. The reason why the second regex doesn't work is because it's looking for two or more, yes, but also note that the reason first regex works is because `\s*` part includes 0 of `\s` as well.

Answer (score 7):

`\s+` is not equivalent to `\t` because `\s` does not mean `<space>`, but instead means `<whitespace>`. A literal space (sometimes four of which are used for tabs, depending on the application used to display them) is simply . That is, hitting the spacebar creates a literal space. That's hardly surprising.

`\s\s` will never match a `\t` because since `\t` IS whitespace, `\s` matches it. It will match `\t\t`, but that's because there's two characters of whitespace (both tab characters). When your regex runs `\s\s+`, it's looking for one character of whitespace followed by one, two, three, or really ANY number more. When it reads your regex it does this:

```
\s\s+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/tGIPokXaiZyUm06g)

The `\t` matches the first `\s`, but when it hits the second one your regex spits it back out saying "Oh, nope nevermind."

Your first regex does this:

```
\s\s*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/_PFRkbseWgLrFZtO)

Again, the `\t` matches your first `\s`, and when the regex continues it sees that it doesn't match the second \s so it takes the "high road" instead and jumps over it. That's why `\s\s*` matches, because the `*` quantifier includes "or zero." while the `+` quantifier does not.

Answer (score 5):

> can I say \t is equivalent to \s+ in regular expression.?

No.

```
\t
```

> Match a tab character

`\s+`

> Matches a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks)
>   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving
>   back as needed (greedy) «+»

Answer (score 1):

No way,
\s+ says one or more white spaces
BUT
\t is one of the whitespace ocurring once.

So  ,  \s+ contain \t but vice versa is not true.